# Google Chrome - is this a BUG? Javascript issue? Touchscreen inputs are not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, windows, google-chrome, touch

I have this simple button. It works on the same machine with a USB mouse click, but does not work when tapped via touchscreen (Iiyama touchscreen).

```
<script>
function button_vipanytime() {
  console.log('OK we clicked');
  alert('Touch screen works');// using mouse I get the alert, but when I tap with touchscreen it never executes.

}

/* fail too
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#vip_anytime').click(function() { 
    alert('jquery');  
  });
});
*/
</script>

<div id="vip_anytime" style="" onclick="button_vipanytime(); " >
    <img src="images/sp/vip.png"  style="width:70px; height: 48px;" />
</div>
```

How can i make it compatible with touch input?

Comment: Does it work on other touch devices? E.g. a smart phone?

Comment: YES - it works with other touch-screens, smart phone, tablets. But with Iiyama not.

Comment: I know this sounds silly, but I have to ask - does touch work for other elements - e.g. can you submit a regular, non-JS, HTML form, or click a link, by touching the "submit" button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As screen touching is supported by another set of events, you should add listeners for touch-based events. Try this:

```
$("#vip_anytime").on("touchend", function(e){
 alert("OK we touched");
});
```

This should not replace the normal "click" event, but be added alongside it.

```
$("#vip_anytime").on("click touchend", function(e){
   alert("OK we touched");
});
```

If you require more information, then you might find this helpful: https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html

Edit:

Native JavaScript implementation might go as follows:

```
document.getElementById("vip_anytime").addEventListener("touchend", function(e) {
  alert("OK we touched");
});
```

And lastly, though it is not best practice you might call it by directly in your HTML code, as in your code example:

```
<div id="vip_anytime" ontouchend="button_vipanytime();">click me</div>
```

Comment: OK - Can you do this with Javascript only without JQuery libraries?

Comment: I love the ontouchend="button_vipanytime()" method, you know why? 1) sometimes you load html, css, javascript child code inside a main parent page using ajax method then that is reliable then the other method. Very nice answer thank you.

Comment: ontouchend is valid since which browsers version? (Google chrome we use).